# Point cloud SLAM

Tags: ros, pointclouds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have a problem with the lokalization of my platform when running through corridors or between two tides walls. I tried to use the Hector Mapping but when for example driving the platform up/down a ramp corridor it failed. So, the Hector Mapping see like the platform is not moving(going forward) because has a problem with the scan matching. In my case amcl is not an option because I wont to use the platform without encoders, only IMU, Kinect and laser. So I thought about SLAM with  point clouds. But I do not know if something exist in the ROS world.ANY help??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63565/point-cloud-slam/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

U can look at RGBD slam. It uses an RGBD sensor like kinect or stereo camera. You can go to this link for details   http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-26**:
But does it need encoders ?I wont to use it for a platform without encoders, so without wheel odometry. Is that possible?And is a good option to use in a very limited environments like tidy walls corridors??

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-26**:
It probably wont require odometery readings. Since I havent used the package myself, I am not sure.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-27**:
And do u know if its works well in limited environment like corridors with tidy walls ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-05-27**:
It will work well..

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ethzasl_icp_mapper](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapper?distro=groovy) might be worth a try if you can tilt your laser scanner and generate pointclouds using this approach. In principle, you should also be able to align Kinectpoint clouds but the "tidy environment" you're describing sounds like the potentially higher range, FOV and accuracy of a LIDAR would be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-27**:
Sorry what do you mean by FOV?So I need this ethzasl_icp_mapper package at the top of the Hector Mapping? So can be used together with Hector Mapping or as alone? Is it possible to use this package with A Point Grey Dragonfly2 Firewire camera?Can I generate pointcloud with Poin Grey Firewire camera?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-28**:
And whats the different when I use only pcl library? Why should ethzasl_icp_mapper  work better than pcl (point cloud library)?

**Comment by [Greg S](https://answers.ros.org/users/4943/greg-s/) on 2013-05-30**:
FOV = Field of view of the camera

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-30**:
yes sorry got it already